# How to get Previous December month of Previous Year

Tags: sql

I was trying to get "December" month of previous year, Can someone help me with this..
I was trying below query, but was getting only year but not "December" Month

DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())

DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE())-1

Comment: are you looking for something like this `SELECT extract(year_month from DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -1 YEAR));`

Comment: `DATEADD` and `DATEPART` are SQL-server functions not MySQL functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for something like this `SELECT extract(year_month from DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL -1 YEAR));`

another example where adding 13 months

`SELECT extract(year_month from DATE_ADD(curdate(),INTERVAL 13 MONTH));`

Comment: If the EndDate is 02/12/2017 I would like to add +13 months for the EndDate